# Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/authe/signup from localhost:9000 to 3000 Econnrefused - Nuxt, Vue, VS code

Tags: node.js, vue.js, proxy, nuxt.js, http-proxy

I tried

```
module.exports = {
    middlewares: app => {
      app.use(
        "/api",
        proxy({
          target: "http://localhost:3000/",
          changeOrigin: true
        })
      )
    },
  }
```

Inside my server/server.js and

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",
```

Inside my package.json files but the error still occurred, these did not work. If I missed something or did a typo in my code please point that out. But I think this doesn't work in Nuxt, Vue, and Node.

Thank you!